# Is there a way I can automate setting passwords for a list of users in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

This is my first question on this site so let me get right into it.

I am in Cyber Patriots, a cyber security competition run by the air force. I am the main person for Windows on my team. For the past few years I have been struggling to make a script that will automatize setting the password for users from a list. **I am doing this in batch [Windows]** and currently have a script that works but its not automatic.

Here is the code I currently have

```
:A
net user 
timeout /t 5
echo Change User Password
set /p UER=Which User Password Would You Like To Change?
echo Please Paste Password:
net user %UER% *
goto A
```

What this does, is it lists all the users on the network, then asks for the user you want to choose and takes your input and changes their password.

The method that I listed does work, but it isn't automatic like I want it to be. Is there a way I can make this automatic? I would prefer to stick with batch however if there's a way to do it from some other language that would be great too.

Last thing. My other thought was to somehow read from a file that has all the usernames and passwords. However unlike in Ubuntu there isn't a file that lists the users that I can read from so I don't know how I would go about this.

Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: wait.... _"cyber security competition"_ but you want to hardcode passwords in a script? `:)`

Comment: listing users however is not difficult. you cannot list their passwords thought. see what happens when you do `dir /b c:\Users >output.txt` then read the content of `output.txt`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard As it is a competition, yes I need to automize it. I'm also trying to make it so each user has to change their password on the next login but that's not in this script. It is just hardening the Operating System so while it may not be safe in an actual work enviorment, it's what I need done for this competition.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Also I understand that I can't read their passwords I just need to read their username from a file and then input each of the usernames and input passwords, skipping through all confirmations and stuff and making it fully automatic. It doesn't need to do exactly that, I just figured there may be a way to do it in that sense.

Comment: Well I am a little reluctant to post an answer as I do not have a windows pc to test this on now.and I am not 100% sure of any implications this might have. But for me to give a go at this, I need some info. Do you need to only prompt the user that logs to change his/her username? Or must they select from a list? Listing all users is sort of useless seeing as a non admin cannot changes another persons password.

Comment: Okay so I need to set passwords to get points. That is the main piece. I list the users in order to see a list of who needs passwords. I enter the username and it changes the password. This script is purely for competition purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I simply wrote this to show it can be done, even though I would never do such a thing in a working environment.

```
@echo off
set list=KLMNOPQRST2345UVWXYZabcdefghiABCDEFGHIJjklmnopqrstuvwxyz016789
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
:start
cls
set /a num=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b c:\users') do (
  set /a num+=1
  set "user[!num!]=%%i"
)

for /l %%c in (1,1,%num%) do echo !user[%%c]!
set /p "to_change=Select user to change Password: "
call :passwd
net user %to_change% !pw! >nul 2>&1
echo(
echo New password for '%to_change%' is: !pw!
pause
goto :start
:passwd
set pw=
for /l %%a IN (0,1,8) DO (
  set /a rand=!random! * 62 / 32768 + 1
  for /f %%b in ('echo %%list:~!rand!^,1%%') do set pw=!pw!%%b
)
```

This simply lists all the users as received by `dir /b c:\users` If the user directory is located anywhere else, you would need to update that in the script.

We then prompt to type one of the users as listed, when typed and enter is pressed, it will generate a random password, do the change and then echo the new password which you need to save.

You can amend it to automatically change all of the passwords and just show you what the new passwords are per user, obviously excluding `administrator`

```
@echo off
set list=KLMNOPQRST2345UVWXYZabcdefghiABCDEFGHIJjklmnopqrstuvwxyz016789
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b c:\users') do (
    if /i not "%%i"=="administrator" (
       call :passwd
       net user "%%i" !pw! >nul 2>&1
       echo(
       echo Password for '%%i' is !pw!
  )
)
echo(
pause
goto :eof
:passwd
set pw=
for /l %%a IN (0,1,8) DO (
  set /a rand=!random! * 62 / 32768 + 1
  for /f %%b in ('echo %%list:~!rand!^,1%%') do set pw=!pw!%%b
)
```

If you win anything in the *"Cyber Security Competition"*, remember, sharing is caring `:D`

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to test it in a practice VM a little later today but I really appreciate your help!